# How to create horizontal tree with separated leaves in html/css

Tags: html, css, composite

I've got standard composite structure which I need to transform into HTML. I've already searched internet for Horizontal CSS tree but I can't figure out how to separate leaves from nodes keeping row-like order.

Below is my targeted design of example structure: `(root(node(leaf1, leaf2), leaf3))`
As you can see on picture, root node has two children but its height is composed of all three leaves.

It's important to focus on equal alignment of leaves.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

[image: Tree representation]

Answer (score -1):

If you re using bootstrap to your project i would recommend to you, use [Fluid nesting](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#fluidGridSystem)